# Auto select radio button on Gravity Forms

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to autoselect a radio button based on a URL query parameter but I am wondering how to get it to work with **Gravity Forms**.

[image: Gravity Forms Image]

If the user selects request a demo it will take them to this following link:

```
mysite.com/contact-us/?request-demo=1
```

Whereas if they go to the "contact us" page it just defaults to the standard page as shown in the image.

Comment: says i need atleast 10 reputation

Comment: the overall section for the radio button has a parameter name "request-demo" making the "Request a demo" link point towards /contact-us/?request-demo=1 does not cause the radio button for requesting a demo to be checked.